# Datatables with server side processing issue

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I've got a script to encode a json string, in order to display data on a jquery [datatable](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) format.

However, the page shows nothing! If I make a simple response using jquery .post the data is shown but the table looses its functionality.

Here's what I've done so far

JSON encode script

```
$user = new Users();

$rcs_user = $user->get_all_users();
$response = '';
$arrResp = array();
$arrItems = array();

foreach ($rcs_user as $info)
{


    $arrItems = array(utf8_encode($info->nome),$info->email,$info->permissao,$info->activo,'<span class="tip" >
                    <a  title="Edit" ><img src="images/icon/icon_edit.png" ></a>
                    </span> 
                    <span class="tip" >
                    <a id="1" class="Delete"  name="Band ring" title="Delete"  >
                    <img src="images/icon/icon_delete.png" >
                    </a></span>');
    array_push($arrResp, $arrItems);

}
$array = array("aaData"=>$arrResp);

echo json_encode($array);
```

JSON String that the script outputs (Validated with JSONLint)

```
{
"aaData": [
    [
        "admin",
        "a@a.pt",
        "1",
        "1",
        "\r\n  </a>\r\n </span> \r\n \r\n \r\n  \r\n </a></span>"
    ],
    [
        "admin2",
        "a@a.pt",
        "1",
        "1",
        "\r\n  </a>\r\n </span> \r\n \r\n \r\n  \r\n </a></span>"
    ],
    [
        "António",
        "a@a.com",
        "10",
        "0",
        "\r\n  </a>\r\n </span> \r\n \r\n \r\n  \r\n </a></span>"
    ],
    [
        "João Dias",
        "a@a.com",
        "10",
        "0",
        "\r\n  </a>\r\n </span> \r\n \r\n \r\n  \r\n </a></span>"
    ],
    [
        "Zé Manel",
        "zemanel@ze.com",
        "10",
        "1",
        "\r\n  </a>\r\n </span> \r\n \r\n \r\n  \r\n </a></span>"
    ]
]
}
```

And finally the jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#data_table3').dataTable( {
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": 'modules/user/showusers.php'
                } );
            } );
```

Each time I reload the page I got this alert message

```
Datatables Warining (tableid = data_table3): Cannot reinitialize table data. To retrieve the Data Objects for this table pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve or bDestroy.
```

It would be a huge help if I get this working!

Comment: How about narrowing down the problem just a little bit for us?

Comment: What about clearing the table with fnClearTable before (re)loading data?

Comment: @hakre, the problem is the error message in the bottom of the post. Basicaly, i don't get any data and I get that error

Comment: @Wrikken I got the same problem with it

Comment: @JoãoDias: hm, looking at http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.1/jquery.dataTables.js it seems using the same table twice also gives problems... Are you sure you are only initialising the table once? If so, got a minimal use case with the correspondng HTML somewhere?

Comment: but i'm just using it once :S

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you are doing server processing manually, then you need to add following parameters to the response:

- `iTotalRecords` - total records in your database
- `iTotalDisplayRecords` - how many records to display

They should be at the same "level" as `aaData` parameter in JSON response. Please see DataTables guide, usage of those fields should be explained there.

Comment: I'll try whith this parameters and post a reply ASAP